# C# Issues with Multi-Threading and Socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, sockets

First of all, I just want to let you know that I am not new to programming, it should be easier to help me :)

I am having issues with my Multi-Threaded Chat that I am making in C# with Socket.

I have 3 threads :

- void ListenSocketConnection : Check for Socket that could connect. Connected Socket are added into a List<>
- void CheckIfClientStillConnectedThread : Check if a Socket disconnected. Disconnected Socket are removed from List<>
- void ReceiveDataListener : Check if a Socket received data

  - Here is the issue. If the first or second thread remove a Socket from the List<>, the 'foreach (ClientManager cManager in clientsList)' will raise an exception.
  - Here is the second issue. If a socket disconnect during that foreach, 'foreach ClientManager cManager in clientsList)' will raise an exception : DisposedException

Do you have any tips on how I could fix this?

Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace JAChat.Library
{
    class SocketServer
    {
        private Socket socketServer;
        private BackgroundWorker bwSocketConnectListener;
        private BackgroundWorker bwCheckIfConnected;
        private BackgroundWorker bwReceiveDataListener;
        private List<ClientManager> clientsList;

        #region Constructor
        public SocketServer(int port)
        {
            clientsList = new List<ClientManager>();

            socketServer = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socketServer.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            socketServer.Listen(100);

            bwSocketConnectListener = new BackgroundWorker();
            bwSocketConnectListener.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(ListenSocketConnection);
            bwSocketConnectListener.RunWorkerAsync();

            bwCheckIfConnected = new BackgroundWorker();
            bwCheckIfConnected.DoWork += CheckIfClientStillConnectedThread;
            bwCheckIfConnected.RunWorkerAsync();

            bwReceiveDataListener = new BackgroundWorker();
            bwReceiveDataListener.DoWork += ReceiveDataListener;
            bwReceiveDataListener.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Getter
        public List<ClientManager> connectedClients
        {
            get
            {
                return clientsList;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Parse and send the command object to targets
        /// </summary>
        public void sendCommand(Command cmd)
        {
            BackgroundWorker test = new BackgroundWorker();
            test.DoWork += delegate {
                foreach(ClientManager cManager in clientsList){
                    cManager.sendCommand(cmd);
                }
            };
            test.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disconnect and close the socket
        /// </summary>
        public void Disconnect()
        {
            socketServer.Disconnect(false);
            socketServer.Close();
            socketServer = null; //Stop some background worker
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void ListenSocketConnection(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (socketServer != null)
            {
                //Get and WAIT for new connection
                ClientManager newClientManager = new ClientManager(socketServer.Accept());
                clientsList.Add(newClientManager);
                onClientConnect.Invoke(newClientManager);
            }
        }

        private void CheckIfClientStillConnectedThread(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
            while(socketServer != null){
                for(int i=0;i<clientsList.Count;i++){
                    if(clientsList[i].socket.Poll(10,SelectMode.SelectRead) && clientsList[i].socket.Available==0){
                        clientsList[i].socket.Close();
                        onClientDisconnect.Invoke(clientsList[i]);
                        clientsList.Remove(clientsList[i]);
                        i--;                        
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
        }

        private void ReceiveDataListener(object unused1, DoWorkEventArgs unused2){
            while (socketServer != null){
                foreach (ClientManager cManager in clientsList)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (cManager.socket.Available > 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Receive Data Listener 0");
                            //Read the command's Type.
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
                            int readBytes = cManager.socket.Receive(buffer, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
                            Console.WriteLine("Receive Data Listener 1");
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;
                            Console.WriteLine("Receive Data Listener 2");
                            CommandType cmdType = (CommandType)(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0));
                            Console.WriteLine("Receive Data Listener 3");

                            //Read the sender IP size.
                            buffer = new byte[4];
                            readBytes = cManager.socket.Receive(buffer, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;
                            int senderIPSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

                            //Read the sender IP.
                            buffer = new byte[senderIPSize];
                            readBytes = cManager.socket.Receive(buffer, 0, senderIPSize, SocketFlags.None);
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;
                            IPAddress cmdSenderIP = IPAddress.Parse(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));

                            //Read the sender name size.
                            buffer = new byte[4];
                            readBytes = cManager.socket.Receive(buffer, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;
                            int senderNameSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

                            //Read the sender name.
                            buffer = new byte[senderNameSize];
                            readBytes = cManager.socket.Receive(buffer, 0, senderNameSize, SocketFlags.None);
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;
                            string cmdSenderName = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);

                            //Read target IP size.
                            string cmdTarget = "";
                            buffer = new byte[4];
                            readBytes = cManager.socket.Receive(buffer, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;
                            int targetIPSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

                            //Read the command's target.
                            buffer = new byte[targetIPSize];
                            readBytes = cManager.socket.Receive(buffer, 0, targetIPSize, SocketFlags.None);
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;
                            cmdTarget = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

                            //Read the command's MetaData size.
                            string cmdMetaData = "";
                            buffer = new byte[4];
                            readBytes = cManager.socket.Receive(buffer, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;
                            int metaDataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

                            //Read the command's Meta data.
                            buffer = new byte[metaDataSize];
                            readBytes = cManager.socket.Receive(buffer, 0, metaDataSize, SocketFlags.None);
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;
                            cmdMetaData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);

                            //Create the command object
                            Command cmd = new Command(cmdType, cmdSenderIP, cmdSenderName, IPAddress.Parse(cmdTarget), cmdMetaData);
                            this.onCommandReceived(cmd);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ObjectDisposedException) {/*Le socket s'est déconnectée pendant le for each. Ignore l'érreur et retourne dans le while*/ }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException) { /* clientsList a été modifié pendant le foreach et délanche une exception. Retour while*/}
                }                
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Receive data listener closed");
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events
        public delegate void OnClientConnectEventHandler(ClientManager client);
        /// <summary>
        /// Events invoked when a client connect to the server
        /// </summary>
        public event OnClientConnectEventHandler onClientConnect = delegate { };

        public delegate void OnClientDisconnectEventHandler(ClientManager client);
        /// <summary>
        /// Events invoked when a client disconnect from the server
        /// </summary>
        public event OnClientDisconnectEventHandler onClientDisconnect = delegate { };

        public delegate void OnCommandReceivedEventHandler(Command cmd);
        /// <summary>
        /// Events invoked when a command has been sent to the server
        /// </summary>
        public event OnCommandReceivedEventHandler onCommandReceived = delegate { };
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: *the one that checks if sockets received that often raises exceptions. Why?* What exception?

Comment: Any reason for not using `Asynchronous` sockets?

Comment: @usr I think you missed to read first line. OP explicitly stated that *I am not new to programming*

Comment: That is right, I am not new to programming :) I am sorry if the explaination wasn't clear, please take a look I edited the OP :)

Answer (score 4):

1. There are multiple threads but I don't see any synchronization. That's incorrect. Use a lock to protect mutable shared state.
2. Instead of having this central management of all sockets, the polling and the checking of `DataAvailable`, why don't you just use either one thread per socket or async IO? That way you only ever manage one socket at a time. No polling necessary. You just call `Read` (or its async version) and wait for the data to arrive. This is a much better paradigm to deal with sockets. Basically, if your socket code contains `DataAvailable` or polling, you are going against best-practices (and likely have a bug somewhere). Think about how you would solve this without using the two. It is possible, and better.
3. In `ReceiveDataListener` you assume, that if data is available that an entire message is available. That's wrong because TCP is stream-oriented. You can receive the sent data in arbitrarily small chunks. Going with my point (2) fixes this.

To elaborate on (2): this is basically an actor model. One actor per socket. Whether you implement the actor using a thread, using `async/await` or using legacy async IO does not matter.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask follow-up questions in the comments below.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am used to Thread using either BackgroundWorket or 'new Thread()' However you look to be talking about something different and I am unsure to understand. Also, wouldn't it be wrong creating one thread per socket? I mean too many threads is not really good ? Do you have maybe a good example that could illustrate what you're trying to tell me? Thanks :)

Comment: One thread/task/backgroundworker per socket is almost always ok if there are few sockets (like dozens). If you have more, use async IO, not polling. For how async IO works on C# 4 here is a solidly looking example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx. On C# 5 you would use `async/await` making this almost trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The collection is being modified by multiple threads, so the count may very every time it is interrogated.  As such, you should set it to a fixed amount; ie before the loop and then iterate through the list.  Also, a count down rather than a count up is a better option since you are removing the elements.

Consider the following code :

```
private void CheckIfClientStillConnectedThread(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (socketServer != null)
    {
        int count = clientsList.Count -1;
        for (int i=count; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            if (clientsList[i].socket.Poll(10, SelectMode.SelectRead) && clientsList[i].socket.Available == 0)
            {
                clientsList[i].socket.Close();
                onClientDisconnect.Invoke(clientsList[i]);
                clientsList.Remove(clientsList[i]);
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha thanks it is true that could avoid some exceptions if some stuffs are being added or removed from the list. Thanks for the tips!